# How to list file(s) created today in a directory using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, sorting, io, .net-2.0

I am using the following code to sort all files in directory in descending order and then checking if file creation date is today's date.

Can this be improved to include .Where() condition at the end to only include files that were created today?

Code

```
Dim orderedFiles = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\\MyFolder").GetFiles().OrderByDescending(Function(p) p.LastWriteTime)
```

Comment: In my case system date will always be right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code just use `Where(Function(p) p.CreationTime.Date = Now.Date)` in lieu of `OrderByDescending(Function(p) p.LastWriteTime)`

```
 Dim orderedFiles = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\MyFolder") _
                              .GetFiles() _
                              .Where(Function(p) p.CreationTime.Date = Now.Date)
```

---

***or***

```
Dim Dir As New DirectoryInfo("C:\MyFolder")
Dim FilesInDir As FileSystemInfo()
FilesInDir = Dir.GetFileSystemInfos
Dim my_file = FilesInDir.Where(Function(p) p.CreationTime.Date = Now.Date)
```

- `my_file` stores collection of files that created today

  ```
  Dim file_name As String
  file_name = my_file(0).FullName ' file in 0th position or you can loop thorough my_file
  ```
- This will show you the file name with absolute path i.e `C:\MyFolder\file.txt`